# Aura Component Spinner Inverse Color

Tags: lightning, aura, component

I want to make my spinner in my modal to go darker but the CSS was not working.

CSS:

```
.THIS.loading_wheel {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    height: 80px;
}
```

MarkUp:

```
 <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium slds-is-relative" id="modal-content-id-1">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
           <!-- Loading wheel -->
           <div class="loading_wheel">
               <aura:if isTrue="{! v.loading }">
                   <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="large" variant="brand"/>
               </aura:if>
           </div>
           ....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can target inner spinner class in lightning spinner

```
.THIS .slds-spinner :before {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}

.THIS .slds-spinner :after {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
.THIS .slds-spinner:before {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}

.THIS .slds-spinner:after {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
```

Though this work there might be some other easier way